# How can I get the total number of posts for a user that have a certain tag in them?

Tags: discussion, tags, search, data-explorer

User [abbood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766570/abbood) (myself) has [eight posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:766570%20%5Bcocoapods%5D) (in total) that have the tag `cocoapods`; six questions and two answers.

I thought that this query should simply get all eight:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   posts p
       JOIN posttags pt
         ON p.id = pt.postid
       JOIN tags t
         ON t.id = pt.tagid
WHERE  owneruserid = 766570
       AND t.tagname = 'cocoapods'
```

but instead it only got six.

It turns out that posts that are answers are not associated with tags. So for example this query

```
SELECT *
FROM   posttags
WHERE  postid IN (SELECT p.id AS 'post id'
                  FROM   posts p
                  WHERE  p.owneruserid = 766570
                         AND p.posttypeid = 1)  // posttypeid = 1 is a question
```

returns many results, whereas this query

```
SELECT *
FROM   posttags
WHERE  postid IN (SELECT p.id AS 'post id'
                  FROM   posts p
                  WHERE  p.owneruserid = 766570
                         AND p.posttypeid = 2)
```

returns zero results.

How can I get the total number of posts (both questions and answers) for a specific user for a specific tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387104/295232) is correct, but the query can be a lot simpler. Questions and answers are joined by `Posts.ParentId` - for answers, that's filled with the `Posts.Id` of the question. So you can simply join `Posts` with `PostTags` on the first non-null value of `ParentId` and `Id`. You can see it in action [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1716139/number-of-posts-by-a-user-in-a-certain-tag?TagName=cocoapods&UserId=766570).

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Posts AS p
  INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt
    ON COALESCE(p.ParentId, p.Id) = pt.PostId
  INNER JOIN Tags AS t
    ON t.Id = pt.TagId
  WHERE p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
    AND t.TagName = '##TagName##'
```

Comment: Simpler, yes (+1), but I think the union really drives home the distinction for someone just learning the data model.

Answer (score 3):

PostTags are only associated with a *question*. So for all the *questions* a user posted in a specific tag, you do a simple join. For the *answers*, you need to check all of their answers, and then determine which ones belong to a question (usually authored by a different user) that have the same tag. Of course in this step you need to filter out self-answers because you already counted the corresponding question. So:

```
DECLARE @tagId int; -- simplify later joins!
SELECT @tagId = Id FROM Tags WHERE TagName = N'##TagName##';

SELECT Total = SUM(c) FROM
(
  -- first, get the questions this user wrote in that tag
  SELECT c = COUNT(*)
  FROM Posts AS p
  INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt
          ON p.Id = pt.PostId
  WHERE p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
    AND p.PostTypeId = 1 -- question
    AND pt.TagId = @tagId
    
  UNION ALL
  
  -- now get their answers to questions on the tag, but filter 
  -- out this user's questions because they're already counted
  SELECT c = COUNT(*)
  FROM Posts AS a
  WHERE a.PostTypeId = 2 -- answer
    AND a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
    AND EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM Posts AS q
        INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt
           ON q.Id = pt.PostId
        WHERE q.OwnerUserId <> ##UserId##
          AND q.PostTypeId = 1 -- question
          AND pt.TagId = @tagId
          AND q.Id = a.ParentId
    )
) AS subquery;
```

- [Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1716136/q387102?TagName=cocoapods&UserId=766570)