# How do I get the highest posters for a certain tag in a specific country?

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer, tag-score, location

I would like to get the user IDs, user names, the number of posts, and the total score for a certain tag for each user in a specific country (sorted in descending order by score).

For example, in the search query I would enter "Lebanon" for country and "iOS" for the tag, and the result would be something like this (the first entry is real, [my own](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766570/abbood)!):

| userID | userName | NumPosts | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 766570 | abbood | 171 | 860 |
| 63343 | mike1515 | 200 | 700 |
| 532342 | superman | 50 | 600 |

This should match with what appears on the user's profile, for example, for the first user:

[image: Tags section]

### Help/References

- I tried something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1309395), but it is very simplistic
- [This query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387105/212196) basically gets the number of posts per user

Comment: IP addresses shouldn't be accessible to the users, only staff. Where do people list their country of origin? (I know that I never have). Are you talking about the Teams product?

Comment: @W.O. "Where do people list their country of origin". In their profile. E.g., you live in Squid central.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Fair enough. I'm just wary of reading too-much into data re the self selected group that would put their *actual* location there. Hmm, maybe they're the ones you see without the tin-foil hats.

Comment: A related older question: [Query for getting top users on a specific tag by country sorted by tag score (Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383074). There is the usual caveat that location field can contain various things (e.g., city rather than country). And the city with the same name can be in various countries. Handling such exceptions can be a rather cumbersome task. As am example, I will add this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1400175
It arose from the discussion here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348060

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1716392/top-users-in-a-certain-tag-from-a-specific-location?Location=lebanon&TagName=ios) does the job. The tricky thing is that only answers count for the score, and Community Wiki posts are excluded. Also, the query assumes everybody uses the same spelling for the location. Some users put a fake location, or maybe just the town or region, or an abbreviation of the country.

[image]

I've added the Location column, because as @Martin noted in the comments, toponyms are often reused (especially in the USA, by all those expatriates). If you scroll further down, you'll see 'Lebanon, TN, USA' and 'Lebanon, IL, USA'.

Comment: In the example you've used, it is perhaps worth mentioning that this would include users from [Lebanon, NH](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1405729/users-with-the-given-string-in-the-location?Location=Lebanon%25NH) and [Lebanon, NJ](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1405729/users-with-the-given-string-in-the-location?Location=Lebanon%25NJ), if some users from there are active in the given tag. (It doesn't seem to be case for the tag [ios] - but maybe for some other tags the situation might be different.)

Comment: @Martin yeah, Georgia (Eurasian country and US state) is another example ...

Comment: @Glorfindel can you edit the query to also include as a column the date of the most recent post?

Comment: @abbood sure, done